# Cocoa Binding, does it matter if the view or the controller is the receiver?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, binding

Using [Apple's Examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/HowDoBindingsWork.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002373-CJBEJBHH), is there a difference between:

`[joystick bind:@"angle" toObject:GraphicController withKeyPath:@"selection.shadowAngle" options:options];`

and

`[GraphicController bind:@"selection.shadowAngle" toObject:joystick withKeyPath:@"angle" options:options];`

So according to the documentation, binding sets it up so using KVO, the receiver observes the object, and uses KVC to set properties on the object.  Here are the relevant figures they provide.

[image]

[image]

But in my mind, I don't see why this couldn't be flipped?  Why can't the controller observe changes to the values on the view w/ KVO, and why can't it set values on the view w/ KVC?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it matters.

First, not all binding names are property names. For example, `NSTextField` has a `"value"` binding (you could use the `NSValueBinding` constant), but it has no `value` property.

Second, not all properties are KVO-compliant. In general, the assumption must be that a property is **not** KVO-compliant unless it is documented to be. Many properties of views are not KVO-compliant. A binding that has the same name can still work, because the class implements the binding and knows when its own internal state changes without relying on KVO.

Third, it is usually the case that there needs to be a specific implementation of `-bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` on the receiver to implement the binding. `NSObject` provides a default implementation of the `NSKeyValueBindingCreation` informal protocol, but it is fairly limited. For example, it is read-only. It observes the `observableController` for changes in the property at the key path and forwards new values to the property on the receiver named by the binding name, but it does not do the reverse. Changes to the receiver's properties will not be forwarded to the `observableController` at the key path.

That's usually not what you wanted from a binding, especially if you reverse the roles.  So, you need a custom implementation. The documentation that you linked to shows how such a custom implementation of `-bind:...` could be written.

Finally, there are services that controllers perform when they are bound *to* that they can't perform when they are thing whose binding is being set. This mostly centers around the `NSEditor` and `NSEditorRegistration` protocols and the implementation of them on `NSController` (which is inherited by its subclasses).

For example, when a text field is bound to a controller, it registers itself with that controller when it starts editing. Later, some other code needs to be sure editing is complete and all bindings have been updated to reflect that editing. It calls one of the `-commitEditing...` methods on the controller. This will, in turn, call `-commitEditing...` on the text field.

This doesn't work if the roles are reversed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't even realize the documentation had an example of implementing `-bind`, I guess just reading documentation all day made my mind mush.  Cheers :)

Comment: Ah wait, one more question-- you said that the default implementation of `bind` is read-only, but I'm confused because the documentation seems to be saying that the receiver uses KVC to modify the property on the observed object?

Comment: I guess I'm mostly confused when I need to be overriding the default implementation of `bind`

Comment: A read-only binding is one which observes and reads from a property of the `observableController` at the key path and modifies the property of the receiver. It does not *write to* a property of the `observableController`. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/Concepts/BindingTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002305-SW1) for the documentation. You would only need to implement `-bind:...` yourself if you're implementing a custom binding for a custom class. If you are, and if the binding is not to be read-only, then you probably do.

Comment: @KenThomases great answer! I can't figure out one thing, makes no sense – I have a textfield bound to two sliders using `tf.bind(…)`, but only the last bound slider gets the updates. Is that by design? One to one relations only?

Comment: The first parameter to `bind(…)` is the name of the binding of the receiver that you wish to bind. Each binding can only be bound to a single object and key path. So, yes, it's expected that calling `bind(…)` again with the same binding would replace the earlier one.